# Creating a post build copy task with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am struggling with the Gradle build lifecycle; specifically with the split between the `configuration` and `execution` phases. I have read a number of sections in the Gradle manual and have seen a number of ideas online, but have not found a solution to the following problem:

*I want to run a specific task to produce an artifact at the end of my `java-library-distribution` build that is a flattened version of the `runtime` configuration jars. That is, I only want to produce the artifact when I run the specific task to create the artifact.*

I have created the following task:

```
task packageSamplerTask(type: Tar, dependsOn: distTar) {
    description "Packages the build jars including dependencies as a flattened tar file. Artifact: ${distsDir}/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.tar"
    from tarTree("${distsDir}/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.tar").files
    classifier = 'dist'
    into "${distsDir}/${archivesBaseName}-dist-${version}.tar"
}
```

Although this task does produce the required artifact, the task runs during gradle's `configuration` phase. This behavior has the following consequences:

- Irrespective of which task I run from the command line, this `packageSamplerTask` task is always run, often unnecessarily; and
- If I `clean` the project, then the build fails on the next run because `$distsDir` doesn't exist during the `configuration` phase (obviously).

It appears that if I extend the `Copy` task in this manner I'm always going to get this kind of *premature* behavior.

Is there a way to use the `<< closure` / `doLast` declarations to get what I want? Or is there something else I'm missing / should be doing?

***Update***

After further work I have clarified my requirements, and resolved my question as follows (specifically):

> *"I want to package my code and my code's dependencies as a flat archive of jars that can be deployed as a jMeter plugin. The package can then be installed by unpacking into the jMeter `lib/ext` directory, as is. The package, therefore, must not include the jMeter jars (and their dependencies) which are used for building and testing"*

Because `Gradle` doesn't appear to support the *Maven-like* `provided` dependency management, I created a new configuration for my package which excludes the jMeter jars.

```
configurations {
    jmpackage {
        extendsFrom runtime
        exclude group: 'org.apache.jmeter', name: 'ApacheJMeter_core', version: '2.11'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.jmeter', name: 'ApacheJMeter_java', version: '2.11'
    }
}
```

And then created the following task (using the closure recommendation from Peter Niederwieser):

```
task packageSamplerTask(type: Tar, dependsOn: assemble) {
    from { libsDir }
    from { configurations.jmpackage.getAsFileTree() }
    classifier = 'dist'
}
```

This solution appears to work, and it allows me to use just the`Gradle` `java` plugin, too.

Comment: Where does `distsDir` come from?

Comment: @Opal Thanks for your interest. The `distsDir` variable is set as part of Java Plugin. You'll find it mentioned in the Gradle documentation [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task declaration is fine, but the flattening needs to be deferred too:

```
...
from { tarTree("${distsDir}/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.tar").files }
```

Also, the Tar file should be referred to in a more abstract way. For example:

```
from { tarTree(distTar.archivePath).files }
```

Answer (score 0):

First your task isn't executed in the `configuration phase` but like EVERY task it is configured in that phase. And your closure is just a configuration of your task (a Configuration closure, not an Action closure). That is why your code is "executed" in the configuration phase".

If you want your code to be executed in the `execution phase` have to write it in a `doLast`closure or `doFirst`. But in your case it is better to keep it in a configuration closure, because you are configuring your task.

To make sure your build doesn't fail because of the missing folder, you can create it with `distsDir.mkdirs()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. The task is used to repackage the `runtime` artefacts from the build, including my own code.  Simply making the `distsDir` may prevent the task from failing but the task will still be *executed* each time any task target is invoked. I only want to invoke this task when I request it, or as a dependency on some other task I request. Depending on the size of the build artefact, this task can have a noticeable impact on the elapsed time of the build when this task runs every time.